# Implement setText:(NSString*)text method in subclassed UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, subclass

I'm subclassing `UITextField` and need a way to run some code whenever the text in the field changes, how can I do this?

(Writing the logic inside this class would let me write cleaner code outside it... I mean that I can do what I'm asking you using the `UITextFieldDelegate`, but I can access it only from outside the class.)

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same use case of needing a custom clear button. I tried subclassing UITextField hoping that I could override setText: but that turned out to be a dead end as it isn't called every time a characters is typed or deleted as I hoped.  I came up with the following solution:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    UIButton *clearButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    [clearButton setTitle:@"x" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clearText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    self.rightView = clearButton;
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)textChanged:(UITextField *)sender {
    self.rightViewMode = sender.text.length > 0 ? UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing : UITextFieldViewModeNever;
}

- (void)clearText:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.text = @"";
    [self textChanged:self];
}
```

Using the UIControlEventEditingChanged we can react to changes in text brought about by the keyboard but not by setting the text in code. Since I also want to respond to text brought about by the clearText: method I have to call the textChanged: method manually following the clear.  If the text is set in code elsewhere there would be a need to call textChanged to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

In .h file of your viewcontroller just define this deledate

```
@interface  yourviewcontroller <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

After that in .m file use bellow code..

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

              .....Do Somthing Here....

}
```

this is delegate method when textfield text changed this method called everytime 
.

Answer (score -1):

How is the code cleaner outside of it by **not** using the UITextFieldDelegate method? You're kind of breaking the MVC design paradigm by trying to tell a view class (your UITextField) how to respond to changes, which is what a controller is meant to do. Could you give a little more insight into why you think it's cleaner to override setText as opposed to handling things in your delegate implementation?

Comment: UITextField is a view class. NSString is the model class here.

Comment: I need this to create a custom clear button, so the code to execute would be the one to make the button disappear when there is no text and the one to clear the text in the field.

Comment: Still not seeing why you wouldn't use UITextFieldDelegate. First of all, you're breaking MVC. Secondly, you're trying to reinvent the wheel. The functionality already exists. Leverage the API!

Comment: This isn't an answer (more of a comment dismissing the question as invalid). Anyway to further the commentary: by moving the logic to UITextFieldDelegate implementers are forced to repeat themselves everytime they wish to use this subclassed UITextField.